# How to change start page in Windows 8.1 store app C#

Tags: c#, windows, store

I am building an app using a split page. I have tried without success to have it start at the split page not the main page or the items page when using the split app template. I have changed the code in the app.cs and the package manifest and nothing works. This is the code I changed in app.cs.

```
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
           if(rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ItemsPage), e.Arguments));
        }
```

I changed this to SplitPage and it just fails.

I have experimented and I can add a blank page and make it open with that. I am sure it has something to do with the navigation code but surely there is some kind of simple override so people can personalize their apps. I really get tired of having to write everything from scratch because I have to read 5 different pages of code behind and try to figure out how they're interacting and it's actually easier to write yourself than use the templates or pages when it should be the opposite. JMO.

I've done a lot of searching but everything I've found is written for VS 2012 and Windows 8.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "It just fails" is not a question. Just a guess, but have you added content to each part of your split page template? Depending on the type if UIElements you're using, they may be collapsed (auto-sized to 0).

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it using a JSON file for data. In fact, I can see it in the visual editor. Using a generic Split App with default data and changing the code in app.cs as indicated above, I get the following exceptions.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it using a JSON file for data. In fact, I can see it in the visual editor. Using a generic Split App with default data and changing the code in app.cs as indicated above, I get too many exceptions to list. It says the "object reference is not set to an instance of the object." This is in the App.g.i.cs generated file. You can add a blank page and make it the start up page because it has no navigation parameters to conflict where they are conflicting. I really have no idea. It's the first time I've ever used this template or page and I've never run into anything like this before.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't mess with `App.g.i.cs`. It would be better just to delete it, [define your own entry point](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/09/how_to_write_custom_main_metho.html) and set your own startup object to [prevent it from coming back](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23041153/2596334).